# Extracting raster using values in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have an original .tif file which has values ranging from 2 to 28. From that original .tif file, I am extracting cells having a value of >=10 using the following code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/2-25-16/HSA"

outws="C:/Subhasis/Test/2-25-16/HSA/HSA_10"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inraster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")


for i in inraster:
    flds = ("VALUE", "COUNT")  
    dct = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(i, flds)}  
    sumcnt = sum(dct.values())
    dct1 = {k:v for (k,v) in dct.items() if k >= 10}
    sumcnt1 = sum(dct1.values())
    percentage=(float(sumcnt1)/float(sumcnt))
    print i,percentage
    newraster = ExtractByAttributes(str(i), "VALUE>=10")
    outname=os.path.join(outws,str(i))
    newraster.save(outname)
```

The code is working. However, when I open the new extracted tif file in GIS, I found that the cell values range from 10 to 30 instead of 10 to 28.

Comment: Have you tried using `newraster = ExtractByAttributes(str(i), "VALUE>=10 AND VALUE<=28")`?

Comment: Would suggest that 30 is a value in the raster. If the attribute table is out of date then this could happen. Suggest you try and rebuild the attribute table for a raster that is returning 30?

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend using the numpy library. you can convert a raster to a matrix, then you can extract all values >10 in literally 1 line, then convert it back into a raster file.

use the RasterToNumPyArray and NumPyArrayToRaster functions:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm

numpy library:
http://www.numpy.org